# Return Statement != and &&

Tags: android, return

What does it mean the following syntax in the return statement (Android Studio)

```
return activteNetwork != null && activteNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

In particular != and &&

Is it a condition?

Thanks

Comment: It's an `implicit condition` (double, because of the **&&**).

Comment: See this, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Answer (score 0):

The above statements will be evaluated, 
if activteNetwork is not null and activteNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting() returns true, your expression will return true. else it will return false.

EDIT: != and && mean "not equal to" and && represents AND operator. 
Read here for more
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/logical-operators-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

`activteNetwork != null` results into `true` is `activteNetwork` has been instantiated, while  `activteNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()` presumably returns `true` if `activteNetwork` is connected or connecting.

Answer (score 0):

`!=` not equal

`&&` both/and

`activteNetwork != null` means that `activteNetwork` should *not* be `null` if it is not `null` then that part is `true`.

if `activteNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()` is `true` then that part is also `true`

`&&` means if both statements are `true` it is returning `true`